# Hey, how can I validate the user name and password? It's seems that the javascript don't get the values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate the user name and password, if the name and password are correct so by clicking "Enter" the user will move to another browser page But I can't take the values the user wrote to the JS (I put a link to YouTube because I don't know how to link to another HTML page)
I would be very happy for some help.. 
Thanks!

```js
let form = document.getElementById('login').innerHTML;
let password = document.getElementById('passwordbox').innerHTML.value;
let Enter = document.getElementById('Enter').innerHTML.value;
let user = document.getElementById('userlogbox').innerHTML.value;


function check(form)


{
  if (form.userid.value == 'abcd') {
    window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
  } else {
    alert("the username you enterd not match");
  }
}

function check(form) {
  if (form.password.value == '1234') {
    window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
  } else {
    alert("the password you enterd not match");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.login-box {
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.login-box h1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #4caf50;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 13px 0;
}

.textbox {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4caf50;
}

.textbox i {
  width: 26px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.textbox input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<form id='login' class='login'>
  <div id='userlogbox' class="login-box">
    <h1>Sudoku</h1>
    <div class="textbox">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="userid">
    </div>

    <div id='passwordbox' class="textbox">
      <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    </div>

    <button><input id='Enter' type="button" class="btn" value="Enter" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Enter"/>
  </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're retrieving the values on pageload, not on form submission

Comment: Why do you have 2 functions named `check`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m still learning, so it seems like a disaster, but thanks
the thing is that I can't use something we haven't learned yet - `addEventListener`
So I tried to write like that, you helped me a lot, I'd love to hear why you think it doesn't work

JS

```
const form = document.getElementById('login');
const userName = document.getElementById('userId');
const password = document.getElementById('userPassword');
const enterBtn = document.getElementById('enter');

const allowedUser = 'abcd';
const allowedPwd = '1234';

enterBtn.onclick() = function(){

    if (!userName.value || !password.value) {
      prompt('Please enter user & password');
      return;
    }
    else if (password.value != '1234') {
      prompt('Please enter password');
      return;
    }
    else if (userName.value != 'abcd') {
      prompt('Please enter user');
      return;
    }
    else if (userName.value === allowedUser && password.value === allowedPwd) {
      window.location.href = "/Users/ormor/Desktop/Sudoku%20Project%204/Sudoku%20Project/main/";
    }
    else {
      prompt('the username you entered does not match');
      return;
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='ws.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='rows'>


  <form id='login' class='login'>
    <div id='userlogbox' class="login-box">
      <h1>Sudoku</h1>
      <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <input id="userId" type="text" placeholder="username" name="userid">
      </div>

      <div id='passwordbox' class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input id="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
      </div>

      <button id='enter' type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="validCheck()">Enter</button>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
  </div>

  </form>
</body>
<script src='ws.js' defer></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 120px;
    background: url(33v2wnher48y.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 30%;
    background-position: 35px, 35px, 35px, 35px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I did not link validation in html to function in js...
How can this be done right?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove parentesis in your btnEnter.onclick

Answer (score -1):

The code is a disaster (many typo error) and i do not understand very well because you do not check also password...however im try to help you because im studing javascript in this moment.

```
const form = document.getElementById('login');
const userName = document.getElementById('userId');
const password = document.getElementById('userPassword');
const enterBtn = document.getElementById('enter');

const allowedUser = 'abcd';
const allowedPwd = 'something';

enterBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!userName.value || !password.value) {
    alert('Please enter user & passowrd');
    return;
  }
  if (userName.value === allowedUser && password.value === allowedPwd) {
    window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
  } else {
    alert('the username you enterd not match');
  }
});
```

I delete the css file (your html and js are fill of typo error and other bad practice)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <script src='script.js' defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='login' class='login'>

    <div id='userlogbox' class="login-box">
      <h1>Sudoku</h1>
      <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <input id="userId" type="text" placeholder="username" name="userid">
      </div>

      <div id='passwordbox' class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input id="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
      </div>

      <button id='enter' type="button" class="btn">
        Enter
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I’m still learning, so it seems like a disaster, but thanks
the thing is that I can't use something we haven't learned yet - `addEventListener`
So I tried to write like that, you helped me a lot, I'd love to hear why you think it doesn't work

Comment: because you should remove '()' on your listner => enterBtn.onclick

Comment: If i helped you please accept or upvote my answer. I work for help and i recive a -1 ...i think is not right